# iisexpress hangs when starting MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

Given

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
- Target Framework .NET Framework 4.5.2
- System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.2.0

When I start my website project (F5)

Then

- The website loads in the web browser and the web browser keeps loading.

Tried and no difference:

- CTRL+F5 (start without debugging)
- Disables browser link
- Disabled anti-virus
- Start with Chrome

Workaround:

- kill iisexpress.exe
- then it works for one debugging session

What Process Monitor tells me when I view iisexpress.exe activity:

There's an infinite loop of the following registry activity:

> 13:04:58,7285089  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query:
>   Name
>   13:04:58,7285345  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegOpenKey  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  REPARSE Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
>   13:04:58,7285611  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS Desired Access: Maximum Allowed,
>   Granted Access: All Access
>   13:04:58,7285803  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegSetInfoKey   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS KeySetInformationClass:
>   KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
>   13:04:58,7285984  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\Library  SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ,
>   Length: 72, Data: %systemroot%\system32\netfxperf.dll
>   13:04:58,7286241  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\Library  SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ,
>   Length: 72, Data: %systemroot%\system32\netfxperf.dll
>   13:04:58,7286498  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\IsMultiInstance  SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD,
>   Length: 4, Data: 1
>   13:04:58,7286750  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\IsMultiInstance  SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD,
>   Length: 4, Data: 1
>   13:04:58,7287001  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\First Counter    NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
>   13:04:58,7287169  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS 
>   13:04:58,7287547  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query:
>   HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
>   13:04:58,7287790  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query:
>   Name
>   13:04:58,7288042  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegOpenKey  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  REPARSE Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
>   13:04:58,7288303  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS Desired Access: Maximum Allowed,
>   Granted Access: All Access
>   13:04:58,7288494  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegSetInfoKey   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS KeySetInformationClass:
>   KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
>   13:04:58,7288676  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\Library  SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ,
>   Length: 72, Data: %systemroot%\system32\netfxperf.dll
>   13:04:58,7288933  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\Library  SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ,
>   Length: 72, Data: %systemroot%\system32\netfxperf.dll
>   13:04:58,7289194  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\IsMultiInstance  SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD,
>   Length: 4, Data: 1
>   13:04:58,7289446  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\IsMultiInstance  SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD,
>   Length: 4, Data: 1
>   13:04:58,7289693  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance\First Counter    NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
>   13:04:58,7289866  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.NET
>   Memory Cache 4.0\Performance  SUCCESS 
>   13:04:58,7290239  iisexpress.exe  11816   RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query:
>   HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: this was only a temporary workaround, the problem is back.**

**WORKAROUND: kill iisexpress.exe process before restarting the IDE**

This was caused by updating to Tools (1.2) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)

Workaround: uninstall.

Steps to uninstall

1. Go to Programs and Features
2. Find the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 entry, click Change

[image: Setup]

3. **Uncheck** Tools (1.2) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)
4. Click update

[image: Visual Studio Setup]
[image: Visual Studio Setup]