# Why has Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express has stopped responding to any HTTP requests?

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I've been developing a Web Forms ASP.net web application in Visual Studio 2013 without any incident for some time now, but recently I attempted to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 and now every time I launch the project I get stuck waiting for a request.  This isn't a server response (like 500 or 404) it just never responds.  To try and isolate this I've uninstalled every copy of Visual Studio (I had 2012, 2013 and 2015 installed), deleted the `%userprofile%\DocumentsIISExpress` folder, reinstalled just VS 2015, and created a completely empty web project (with just the default Web Forms boilerplate).  Here is a screen shot of what I am experiencing:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem after installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. As it turns out, VS 2015 removes IIS Express 8.0, which was included with Visual Studio 2013, and installs IIS Express 10.0. For some reason, this version of IIS Express does not work for some developers.

- [visual studio iis express not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423358/visual-studio-iis-express-not-working)
- [iisexpress hangs when starting MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395363/iisexpress-hangs-when-starting-mvc-project)
- [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - No IIS Express Response While Debuging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462634/visual-studio-2015-update-1-no-iis-express-response-while-debuging)

As a workaround, I ended up uninstalling IIS Express 10.0 from the Programs and Features control panel, and re-installed IIS Express 8.0. It is available as a separate [download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679).

This appears to have resolved the issues I was experiencing, however I do not know if there are features in iis express 10.0 which vs2015 relies on for debugging and app execution. In the extremely limited testing that I've done with VS 2015 and IIS Express 8.0 everything appears to be working fine YMMV.

**UPDATE:**

While refreshing my OS I noticed that IIS Express 10 was working properly. But when I installed IIS from the Windows Programs and Features dialog, express stopped working and behaved as described above. Others have noticed [this coincidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448862/iisexpress-10-stopped-working-after-installing-iis) as well.

Uninstalling IIS and reinstalling IIS Express 10, in my case, allowed me to debug my web application with IIS Express 10. As always YMMV.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to resolve this! Thanks :)

Comment: I know this is a fairly old post, but I have now found a solution.

After I had performed a refresh of my Windows 10 install, I found that IIS Express 10 was working as expected. But after I installed IIS from the "programs and features" dialog Express 10 stopped working. The coincidence was noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448862/iisexpress-10-stopped-working-after-installing-iis) as well.

After uninstalling IIS and reinstalling IIS Express 10, Visual studio 15 can now debug using IIS express 10 again, for what it is worth.

Comment: Thank you for this update! I'll look into it right now. It would be worth it to add your findings to your original answer.